# Set Wine application icons in Cinnamon or Gnome3

Tags: gnome, wine, cinnamon

[image]

In the above screenshot you can see that I am using a Wine application, Nemo file browser & Firefox, however, I want to use a specific icon for this Wine application too! To be precise I am using PDF Xchange viewer & I want to use its native Windows icon in Cinnamon too!

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create your icon as a png file
2. copy an application file from

   `/usr/share/applications`
3. open it in a text editor
4. customize  it.

You could just copy my template blow, also:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Your App
Comment=Comments shown as tooltip
Exec= wine /path/to/executable
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain; 
Categories=Wine;Applications;
```

Propose:

You're icon should be placed on: `/usr/share/icons/ownicons`

create this directory with

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/myicons/
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername /usr/share/myicons/
```

Look at [Gnome Desktop entry specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)  for more information.

Comment: I am not sure for cinemon 'cause I don't use it if it is based on gnome this should work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I made the new directory, and I put the desktop file, but Cinnamon in Ubuntu 13.10 still shows the stupid Windows logo, I was searching in others forums but this one was the closest to my problem.

I'll show you my desktop file for Microsoft Windows

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Microsoft Word 2010
Comment=
Icon=word.png
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/larry/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/larry/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Office2010/dosdevices/c:/users/larry/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Microsoft\\ Office/Microsoft\\ Word\\ 2010.lnk
NoDisplay=false
Categories=wine-Programs-Microsoft Office;
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=WINWORD.EXE
Encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions indicated here do not solve the issue in Cinnamon. This is a bug in Cinnamon which is tracked under https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/581
This issue remains in Cinnamon 2.4.5

With multiple applications running under wine, this issue creates confusion.

Possible workarounds:

1. Use a dock (such as docky) where this issue is not seen
2. Replace the native wine icons with something more easy on the eyes. If you are mostly using one particular application under wine, this could be the replacement.

For the taskbar icon

```
sudo mv youricon16x16.png /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/16/wine.png
```

For the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> icon

```
sudo mv youricon.svg /usr/share/icons/Mint-X/apps/scalable/wine.svg
```